# Finding "row" field based on condition from yaml which is mapped to class

Tags: java, yaml

```
 T1:
   apis :
     - api: r1
       cnfig :
         - country: M1
           userseg: 5
           row: 4
         - country: M2
           userseg: 11
           row: 10
      - api: r2
       cnfig :
         - country: M1
           userseg: 5
           row: 6
         - country: M2
           userseg: 5
           row: 12
```

i need to find all api name with row number for userseg : 5 , country : M1 in a map with List>>

```
   List<Api> collect = apis
                   .stream().filter(
                           api -> (api.getConfigs().stream()
                                   .filter(singleConfig -> singleConfig.userseg.contains("5")
                                           && singleConfig.country.equals("M1"))
                                   .count() > 0))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But collect is giving me List of all apis and all configs . It is giving me below config :

```
   cnfig :
         - country: M1
           userseg: 5
```

along with other config

```
   cnfig :
         - country: M2
           userseg: 10
```

How can i achieve to get list List>> with above condition ? I expect to get r1,4 and r2,6

Comment: How do you parse your yaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specific on how you want those results to be typed and some type info on your structure is missing, but I'll show you the general idea:

```
List<String> collect = apis.stream().flatMap(api ->
    api.getConfigs().stream().filter(
        singleConfig -> singleConfig.userseg.contains("5")
                     && singleConfig.country.equals("M1")
    ).map(config -> api.getApi() + "," + config.getRow())
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will generate multiple entries if an item in `apis` contains multiple matching configs, based on your data that seems unlikely.